# Missing df command on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, dependencies, df, timeshift

I tried to run TimeShift but got an error saying:
Commands listed below are not available on this system: *df

[image]

I tried to install the df command using sudo apt install coreutils and got a message saying it's already installed and on the latest version.

Uninstalled and installed TimeShift again but the problem persists.

Anyone has an idea of what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: $PATH not correctly set up?
Can you invoke `df` manually?
Or only as `/bin/df` ?

Comment: I don't know if $PATH is correctly set up but I cannot invoke `df`. Nor manually or as `/bin/df`

Comment: Well, is it there? Does `ls -lh /bin/df` show a 83K file? Does `file /bin/df` show an "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object..." ?

Comment: You can verify the md5sum of the package with: `cd /; md5sum --quiet -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/coreutils.md5sums` (no output means everything okay)

Comment: The `ls /bin/df` returns "ls: cannot access '/bin/df': No such file or directory".

And I got a return from the other command, it says:
md5sum: bin/df: No such file or directory
bin/df: FAILED open or read
md5sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read

Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: If `/bin/df` was manually deleted, you may need to use `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`

Comment: Great, `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils` worked.
Thanks @steeldriver